# Is gem supports to all operating system?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Is there any gem performance issue with operating system?
An application which is running perfectly in MAC OS is not working properly in Ubuntu.
Application is not throwing any error but some functionality & some layouts are not proper.
Any solution?
Please comment.
Thanks

Comment: No. Not all gems are supported on all operating systems. Without more information, it is difficult to assist.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What does your gemfile look like? Also, if you can give some parts of code/logs that will help us understand the problem better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**OS**

To answer your question properly, you have to remember that a `gem` is literally just a "plugin" for Ruby (& by virtue, Rails). This means that it will do nothing other than provide "pre-packaged" functionality you can use in your application

The problems you'll likely experience with operating systems will **not** be to do directly with the gem - instead it will be the interface of the gem with the operating system itself.

Let me explain...

---

[**Header Files**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_directive)

The primary issue for Gems is a lack of the appropriate *header files* on your operating system.

Header files are basically the "class" files which various applications require to interface with different technologies:

> Many programming languages and other computer files have a directive,
>   often called include (as well as copy and import), that causes the
>   contents of a second file to be inserted into the original file. These
>   included files are called copybooks or header files. They are often
>   used to define the physical layout of program data, pieces of
>   procedural code and/or forward declarations while promoting
>   encapsulation and the reuse of code.

This is especially true with Windows, but is also an issue on Linux & OSX too. The problem is that when you install a gem which relies on a [third-party dependency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)) (such as [MYSQL](https://medium.com/p/installing-the-mysql2-rubyonrails-gem-on-windows-7-8-a028f44d87f3) or ImageMagick), or does something within the operating system itself (such as Resque), you can end up with issues.

The bottom-line to fixing these is to make sure your system uses the correct *header files* installed for the gem you wish to use.

--

Because different header files exist for different operating systems & gems, you'll have to be specific about your OS & gem in order to gain a workable response!

Comment: hello,my problem was solved. It was because of ruby version installed.